# Indexing PDFs in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, desktop-search

Windows 8's desktop search seems not to index PDFs. Is this by design or have I misconfigured something?

Comment: This issue also can happen on W7 - the answer my also help you http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/i-need-to-index-pdf-files-in-my-laptop-running/ef5fa7c3-bb64-4f3e-9607-3e01349dccca

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows 8 should be able to index PDFs out of the box. Just press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> / type "index" / Indexing Options / Advanced / File Types tab, select PDF and ensure that **Index Properties and File Contents** is selected:

[image: 1]

Also, as per [this Adobe forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4852011), seems like installing Acrobat XI can actually break Win8's PDF indexing ability. Considering the fact that Adobe's iFilter/preview handler+thumbnailing feature has been [broken for more than 3 years now](http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/), this comes as no great surprise to me.  Adobe has responded with [an official workaround](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-search-breaks-110-install.html) to restore the native Windows 8 PDF iFilter functionality.

Comment: It is selected in mine, but it says "Registered IFilter is not found". Can you verify that it works for you? If Acrobat is to blame, I need to find a way to disable its iFilter without uninstalling it altogether.

Comment: I don't have any crap from Adobe installed for handling PDFs, and no PDF iFilter installed either. I just tried changing the Indexing Options and when the *Plain Text Filter* was activated for PDFs instead of the *File Properties Filter*, search correctly found PDFs with the text I specified. The only other PDF iFilter I know of is [Foxit's](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/), but no idea if it works in Windows 8, plus it is not free.

Comment: To be clear, the text it found was inside the PDF, not the title or metadata, correct?

Comment: Yes, it was inside the PDF.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Windows 8.1 with MS Reader, Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader installed:

Change registry key per [Adobe's instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-search-breaks-110-install.html).

Restart (may not be needed).

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, select `Index > Advanced` and click "Rebuild" under Troubleshooting.

Now Windows Explorer shows PDF content in the search results.

Answer (score 2):

This issue also can happen on W7 - the answer my also help you http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/i-need-to-index-pdf-files-in-my-laptop-running/ef5fa7c3-bb64-4f3e-9607-3e01349dccca

So, for Windows 7:

Go to Indexing > Advanced > File Types, and remove the check for PDF. Press OK > Press Close.

Then uninstall any Ifilters that you have relating to searching PDF Files.

Re-install Acrobat if lower than version 9.3

Comment: It says "Registered IFilter is not found". Do Windows 8 or Acrobat XI not come with one?

Comment: I think it is not supported. http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=1&platform=Windows Here you can see what iFilters you can download and it only mentions Windows 7 (despite saying 64bit)