# PDF title does not show in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, pdf, metadata, title

Is there any way to add title to PDF docs?actually I do it but windows 10 does not show PDF Titles in Explorer Columns.I need a way to show it.
Is it correct that Microsoft windows does not support PDF metadatas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Acrobat PDF tags not shown in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/602536/why-are-acrobat-pdf-tags-not-shown-in-windows). You need a third party program (shell extension) for display PDF attributes as Explorer column.

Comment: Open Windows Explorer, View Tab, Add Columns, pull it down, look for Choose Columns, and open that. See if there are columns or columns of file data that serve your purpose.

Comment: @John unfortunately you don't understand my purpose.i tried to show PDF title in windows but windows just show Office file titles

Comment: @Robert I should use builtin Microsoft explorer.I think when i use third party program;i can't use windows index for search in PDFs.is it correct?
the another problem is that i should install this program to many clients.therefore i try to find better solution.for example working with registery.

Comment: @Hamid When you install a third party PDF program that includes a shell-extension the Windows Explorer is getting new features/columns. You don't have to use this program just install it.

Comment: @Robert My PDF docs are located in File Server.in this scenario should i install shell-extension in the server?or clients?or both of them?
do you have direct download link?

Comment: @Hamid Your Windows Explorer runs on your client computer, hence install the software on the client PC of course. The linked SU question contains more than enough software links.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for sharing your knowledge.your solution has worked.now my I should install it for all clients

Comment: @Hamid I am sorry but your question does not make senste to me. It is your decision if and what you install where. And your decision should reflect the needs of the users using that PCs.